How do I fix sudden CORS error from zendesk app?
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://myserver.com/marketplace/foo?test=123. 
(Reason: CORS request did not succeed). 
Status code: (null).

There was a problem with the fetch operation: 

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. 
from origin: https://1061842.apps.zdusercontent.com/

We have an app in production and set:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://1061842.apps.zdusercontent.com
  c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.apps.zdusercontent.com", id))
  c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
  c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

where id comes from 1061842 in the origin.
  origin := c.Request.Header.Get("Origin")

  tokens := strings.Split(origin[8:], ".")
  id := tokens[0]

and it was working fine for months. Then all of a sudden last night we get this error.

CORS errors can often be caused by something else. If anything is preventing a response coming back from the API such as the server has lost its network connection, the CORS pre-flight request will fail then return an error that gets reported as a CORS error. Always worth checking everything else before trying to fix what was a perfectly good CORS config

oh thank you this was exactly it! My cert had expired and no https connections were working without error.

I can't tell you the number of hours I've spent trying to fix CORS errors that turned out to be caused by something completely different. Glad I could help
